# How to declare repositories based on entity interfaces?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In a new project we would like to use Spring Data JPA and define interfaces for all JPA entities, e.g. like this:

```
public interface Person extends Serializable {

  void setId(Long id);

  Long getId();

  void setLastName(String lastName);

  String getLastName();

  void setFirstName(String firstName);

  String getFirstName();

  // ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_persons")
public class PersonEntity implements Person {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String firstName;

  @Column
  private String lastName;

  // ...
}
```

However, when declaring a Spring Data repository based on the interface like

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

}
```

The Spring context fails to initialize with an exception whose cause is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: interface com.example.Person
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: interface com.example.Person
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:171)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:146)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:150)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510)
    ... 34 more
```

I haven't found any example of Repository relying on the interface instead of the concrete type so is this possible at all? And if yes, how?

It seems that if we cannot use the interface to declare the repositories, then it will be very difficult to use those interfaces at all since we will end up with explicit casts everywhere in our services, and even unchecked casts as soon as we deal with generics (`List`, `Iterable`…).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you would use such a feature? What does your use case look like?

Comment: The main point is to reduce coupling between the higher levels and the concrete entity types.

Comment: Also, why not make the entity itself an interface and have spring generate a Pojo implementation?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution to your problem. I don't know why Spring guys decided to base their repositories on concrete classes. But at least they made it possible to change that.

1. You need to provide custom `repositoryFactoryBeanClass` in `EnableJpaRepositories` e.g. something like that:

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

/**
 * @author goraczka
 */
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    repositoryFactoryBeanClass = InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class
)
public class DatabaseConfig {
}
```

2. Then you need to implement `InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactoryBean`. It is a Spring hook to enable creating a custom factory for repository beans.

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

/**
 * @author goraczka
 */
public class InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {

    public InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }
}
```

3. And last but not least the custom repository bean factory that tries to match interface defined on the repository itself with a entity class registered on `EntityManager`.

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * @author goraczka
 */
public class InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private final Map<? extends Class<?>, ? extends Class<?>> interfaceToEntityClassMap;
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

        super(entityManager);

        this.entityManager = entityManager;

        interfaceToEntityClassMap = entityManager
                .getMetamodel()
                .getEntities()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(et -> Arrays.stream(et.getJavaType().getInterfaces())
                        .map(it -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(it, et.getJavaType())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (possibleDuplicateInterface, v) -> v));
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T, ID> JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> getEntityInformation(Class<T> domainClass) {

        Assert.isTrue(domainClass.isInterface(), "You are using interface based jpa repository support. " +
                "The entity type used in DAO should be an interface");

        Class<T> domainInterface = domainClass;

        Class<?> entityClass = interfaceToEntityClassMap.get(domainInterface);

        Assert.notNull(entityClass, "Entity class for a interface" + domainInterface + " not found!");

        return (JpaEntityInformation<T, ID>) JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(entityClass, entityManager);
    }
}
```

Don't bash me for any mistakes. I did it in 10 minutes after reading this question and realizing that there is no solution for it yet. And I really needed one. I did not create any tests for it yet but seems to work. Improvements are welcomed.

Comment: Thanks @goroncy for your answer. Unfortunately I am not on that project anymore, but it seems to be a nice approach.

Comment: How do i do it in mongodb?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and solved it using `@NoRepositoryBean` on the repository interface that uses an interface and not a concrete class in that way (thanks to [that blog post](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/12/18/handling-entities-inheritance-with-spring-data-jpa/)):

```java
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface PersonRepository<P extends Person> extends JpaRepository<P, Long> {
    // code all generic methods using fields in Person interface
}
```

And then, use a concrete repository that extends the other:

```java
public interface PersonEntityRepository extends PersonRepository<PersonEntity> {
    // code all specific methods that use fields in PersonEntity class
}
```

This annotation is at least present in `spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar`.

Answer (score 3):

Following the reply of [@goroncy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281191/goroncy) I also had to override the method *getRepositoryMetadata*

```
@Override
protected RepositoryMetadata getRepositoryMetadata(Class<?> repositoryInterface) {
    RepositoryMetadata ret = super.getRepositoryMetadata(repositoryInterface);
    Class<?> clazz = ret.getClass();
    try {
        Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField("domainType");
        boolean isAccessible = f.isAccessible();
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Class<?> actualValue = (Class<?>) f.get(ret);
        Class<?> newValue = this.interfaceToEntityClassMap.get(actualValue);
        f.set(ret, newValue);
        f.setAccessible(isAccessible);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I added compatibility support for repositories based on entities, not only with interfaces. Enabled by default.

```
private boolean allowNonInterfaceTypes = true;
```

You can disable it by calling the 2-parameter constructor from *InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactoryBean*

```
@Override
protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
    return new InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager, false);
}
```

The full class remain as

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.RepositoryFragments;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

public class InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private final Map<? extends Class<?>, ? extends Class<?>> interfaceToEntityClassMap;
    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private boolean allowNonInterfaceTypes = true;

    public InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

        super(entityManager);

        this.entityManager = entityManager;

        this.interfaceToEntityClassMap = entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream()
                .flatMap(et -> Arrays.stream(et.getJavaType().getInterfaces())
                        .map(it -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(it, et.getJavaType())))
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (possibleDuplicateInterface, v) -> v));

    }

    public InterfaceBasedJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager, boolean paramAllowNonInterfaceTypes) {
        this(entityManager);
        this.allowNonInterfaceTypes = paramAllowNonInterfaceTypes;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T, ID> JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> getEntityInformation(Class<T> domainClass) {

        JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> ret = null;
        // Interface entities
        if (this.allowNonInterfaceTypes == false) {
            Assert.isTrue(domainClass.isInterface(),
                    "You are using interface based jpa repository support. The entity type used in DAO should be an interface");

            Class<T> domainInterface = domainClass;

            Class<?> entityClass = this.interfaceToEntityClassMap.get(domainInterface);

            Assert.notNull(entityClass, String.format("Entity class for a interface %s not found!", domainInterface));

            ret = (JpaEntityInformation<T, ID>) JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(entityClass, entityManager);
        }else {
            // Class entities
            ret = super.getEntityInformation(domainClass);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryMetadata getRepositoryMetadata(Class<?> repositoryInterface) {
        RepositoryMetadata ret = super.getRepositoryMetadata(repositoryInterface);
        Class<?> clazz = ret.getClass();
        try {
            Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField("domainType");
            boolean isAccessible = f.isAccessible();
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Class<?> actualValue = (Class<?>) f.get(ret);
            Class<?> newValue = this.interfaceToEntityClassMap.get(actualValue);
            f.set(ret, newValue);
            f.setAccessible(isAccessible);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

It worked for me with spring-data-jpa 2.0.8.RELEASE taken from spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.0.3.RELEASE

Sorry if there is any mistake, I did it a time ago.

Answer (score -2):

The interface Person lack the @Entity annotation and hence is not recognized as a managed object.
I think that putting the @Entity annotation on the Person interface will not help either as this annotation is not inherited. I think you should either forget about the Person interface or just use the PersonEntity instead in the repository declaration. 
Did not actually check in code - so very sorry if this answer is wrong...

Comment: I don't think the JPA spec normally allows putting the annotations on an interface. Anyway, if I do this, Hibernates complains of the missing @Id on the interface. If I add it, the container starts, but then it tries to perform a query on both `Person` and `t_persons` tables. It seems I have to move all annotations on the interface, but then `PersonEntity` is no more recognized as an entity!

Comment: So why not just give up the interface? Do you have more than 1 implementation for it? I have a perfectly working Spring + Hibernate based webapp and I've never needed to make my entities implement an interface.

Comment: The idea is simply to reduce coupling. With pure JPA we can do it so why not with Spring Data JPA? ;-)

Comment: @DidierL, what do you mean when you say you can do that in pure JPA?

Comment: I mean that JPA allows to use interfaces everywhere, including for relationships where you can tell JPA the concrete class using `targetEntity` while declaring your fields using the interfaces only.